# Merge the two repositories into one with all branches

Tags: git, github, project, bitbucket, git-branch

I have project (one repository) on github and I have another project on bitbucket. Each project has multiply branches.

My question is: Really merge the two repositories into one repository (on github) with all branches. I mean I will have two folders (in each project) and one repository.

I found [this answer](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/). But this way merge only master branches (not all).

Comment: "Each project has multiply branches." with the same name in each repo?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"I will have two folders (in each project)"*

Comment: Yes, my projects have the same branches. For example master.

Comment: I didn't ask about master I asked about other branches

Answer (score 0):

You can use git graft to merge two repositories into one using git graft. Following post may be helpful. Be careful with graft point for moving branches

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/WTqKv9QlOFw